# Weak references to plots in core plot?

Tags: core-plot

I've got a situation where is seems that core-plot is throwing away CPTPlotDataSource objects unless there is another reference to the object. The symptom is that if add six "traces" to a plot, I will see only the last trace added, unless there is another reference to the traces elsewhere
 (objects implementing the CPTPlotDataSource protocol). If there is another external reference to each FreqResponseDataSource object, the plot works perfectly. Here's the code that adds a trace:

```
func addTrace(dataSource: FreqResponseDataSource,
              lineColor: CPTColor = CPTColor.black(),
              title: String? = nil) {
    let plot = CPTScatterPlot(frame: CGRect.zero)
    plot.dataSource = dataSource
    plot.title = title
    let ls1 = CPTMutableLineStyle(style: plot.dataLineStyle)
    ls1.lineColor = lineColor
    ls1.lineWidth = 2.0
    plot.dataLineStyle = ls1
    graph.add(plot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    graph.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot plots hold weak references to their datasources. This is a standard part of the datasource pattern seen throughout Apple's frameworks and is done to prevent retain cycles. The datasource is often implemented in a controller object that is automatically retained by the system. If you want to use a different object as the datasource, you have to keep a persistent reference to it somewhere.